# What's "못할 수도 있지. 되게 뭐라고 하네"

Tags: meaning

This is from Youtube automatic subtitle, so I'm not sure it's a correct sentence though.

Comment: which video is this from and what have you tried in translating it?

Comment: It's a valid sentence whose expected context is where the speaker is being reproved by someone else and is grumbling.

Comment: "Maybe I can't. You're really blame to me" 
but in this sentence, "I" can be someone else, not me. because of omitted subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the situation was something like someone failed to accomplish the mission or made a mistake, and another guy complained about it.

"Not everyone can do that. (or, You can't always succeed.) You're complaining too much."

Comment: So you say that 있지 is a short form for 있지 않다?

Comment: '-지' here is an ending suffix that gives a certain tone to the sentence ([link](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-92-100/lesson-93/)) Here the negation is expressed by the adverb '못'.

Answer (score 2):

### 못할 수도 있지. 되게 뭐라고 하네.

is a correct sentence that's colloquial and friendly sounding.

To break it down:

#### 1. 못할 수도 있지

"못할 수(도) 있지" is a common phrase for saying "It's okay." in English, and that's usually spoken when you forgive(or be generous towards) someone who couldn't carry out his/her work well.

So what it means is kinda like, "It's okay, although at the moment you might have not done something well or even made a mistake."

These are some similar expressions:

> - "(잘) (하지) 못할 수(도) 있지"
> - "실수할 수(도) 있지" (Everyone makes mistake.)
> - "그럴 수(도) 있지" (It happens.)

#### 2. 되게 뭐라고 하네

"되게 뭐라고 하네." - This means "You nag too much."